# Cannot create webservices from Oracle APEX

Tags: rest, web-services, plsql, oracle-apex, acl

I am new to Oracle APEX, i am trying to create REST Data Webservices from Oracle APEX 20.2, while creating the web services below are the configuration settings,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykbkC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUj00.png)

So regarding this issue i am trying to execute the APEX ACL Script but it's showing an below error,

```
DECLARE
  ACL_PATH  VARCHAR2(4000);
    ACL_ID    RAW(16);
  BEGIN
    -- Look for the ACL currently assigned to '*' and give APEX_040200
    -- the "connect" privilege if APEX_040200 does not have the privilege yet.

 SELECT ACL INTO ACL_PATH FROM DBA_NETWORK_ACLS
 WHERE HOST = '*' AND LOWER_PORT IS NULL AND UPPER_PORT IS NULL;

  -- Before checking the privilege, ensure that the ACL is valid
  -- (for example, does not contain stale references to dropped users).
  -- If it does, the following exception will be raised:
  --
  -- ORA-44416: Invalid ACL: Unresolved principal 'APEX_040200'
  -- ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XDBZ", line ...
  --
  SELECT SYS_OP_R2O(extractValue(P.RES, '/Resource/XMLRef')) INTO ACL_ID
  FROM XDB.XDB$ACL A, PATH_VIEW P
  WHERE extractValue(P.RES, '/Resource/XMLRef') = REF(A) AND
     EQUALS_PATH(P.RES, ACL_PATH) = 1;

 DBMS_XDBZ.ValidateACL(ACL_ID);
  IF DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CHECK_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH, 'APEX_040200', 
 'connect') IS NULL THEN 
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH, 
 'APEX_040200', TRUE, 'connect'); 
 END IF;

  EXCEPTION
  -- When no ACL has been assigned to '*'.
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL('power_users.xml',
  'ACL that lets power users to connect to everywhere',
  'APEX_040200', TRUE, 'connect');
   DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL('power_users.xml','*');
 END;
/
 COMMIT;
```

ERROR: (I am facing while execute the above script)

```
ORA-06550: line 8, column 33: PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist ORA-06512: at         "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200200", line 670 ORA-06550: line 8, column 3: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored    ORA-06550: line 24, column 7: PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN' must be declared ORA-06550: line 24, column 4: PL/SQL: Statement ignored ORA-06550: line 33, column 3: PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN' must be declared ORA-06550: line 33, column 3: PL/SQL: Statement ignored ORA-06550: line 36, column 3: PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN' must be declared ORA-06550: line 36, column 3: PL/SQL: Statement ignored ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658 ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200200", line 656 ORA-06512: at "APEX_200200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 1768
```

So while i am checking APEX Forum basically we need the connect privilege to create web services, so my question is how to get connect privilege while using apex.oracle.com, I am using testing schema for oracle apex, for that to whom i request to get connect privilege, who is responsible DBA for that, or how to fix this issue.

Thanks In Advance,
Yokes

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to configure ACL if you want to expose restful services. ACL is needed to connect from *invoke* restful service calls from *within* the database, eg from pl/sql.
Typically those scripts are run by a DBA, I doubt you'd have the permissions to run them anyway.

The best place to start with restful services is to install the sample service and investigate the sample module. You can just copy the url of a template with a GET handler in your browser and see the results. From there on start developing your own.
By the way, that script for ACL has the wrong apex user. APEX_040200 was the apex schema for apex 4.2. That is a rather old version. apex.oracle.com has the latest version which currently is 20.2.

Comment: Yes Koen Lostrie thanks for your quick response,can i have any sample module for create web services, even i could not able to create it from oracle apex 20.2, sorry for the inconveniences i am newbie to oracle apex, i am trying to create basic emp table, kindly please let me know if any basic or sample module

Comment: Login to apex.oracle.com in your workspace. Go to SQL Workshop > Restful Services. Register your schema with ORDS (only needs to be done once) with option "Install Sample Service" checked. If you do not check that box you'll still have a button "Install Sample Service" in the "Ords Restful Services" home page.