# RestWebservices in Oracle APEX

Tags: rest, web-services, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-20.2

I am new to Oracle APEX can anyone please let me know how to create Rest Web services in Oracle APEX 20.2 and kindly let me know is there any sample module to build the same.

Thanks & Regards,
Yokeswaran G

Comment: You asked the same question yesterday. I posted instructions on how to install sample module. I'd continue on that thread instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot create webservices from Oracle APEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66530486/cannot-create-webservices-from-oracle-apex)

Comment: Hi Koen Lostrie,

I followed what you are suggested but still i could not able to create a rest web services.

The Server Response Below:

Comment: Discovery error: Application Express cannot compute a data profile from the response data of type: text/html.

Comment: I have enabled the rest services for table departments, and i have disabled the authentication, but while trying to create web services i am facing an above error

Comment: This is a duplicate question. Please move this discussion to the original thread, that way I can update my original answer

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume you understand how restfull services work as a whole. having said that, in Oracle APEX you can

- Access SQL Workshop -> Resftul Services
- click on the Enable ORDS Link (I recommend installing the example it suggests)
- create module (any name)
- inside the module, create a template (any name)
- inside the template, create a GET Handler
- inside the GET handler copy and paste any working select (DO NOT put a semi colon at the end)
- Save

After that you can copy the full URL anywhere and it should be working. I would also advise you to watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fw4ViwS0jqY